# Google App Engine Login vs Application Login

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application deployed on GAE. It allows users to register for an account, and I use the google user id as the primary key to link to their account.

I have a registration link that should be visible if either the user has not been authenticated by google and/or they do not have an account on my site.

What I am trying to figure out is what is the best way to figure out if the user has an account on my site as they go from page to page. I have an authentication filter that is triggered on every page, and the filter looks at their google id (if they are logged in), goes off and determines if the user has an account on my site, and sets a request parameter, that I use in the jsp to determine whether or not to show the registration link.

It seems wasteful to do that every time, so I refactored it and had the authentication filter store the Key object tied to their user account on my site in a Session. If the key attribute is not null, I take that to mean that the user is registered on my site.

Does that seem logical, or are there better approaches? The complexity to me comes from the fact that the user may be logged in with google, but that doesn't necessarily mean they have an account on my site.

My question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to storing authentication data, you have two options :

- Store the data in session
- Store the data on client side, in a cookie typically

Storing the data in session is a perfectly valid mechanism, and that's actually the most common.

However, managing a session is costly (you need to store it). In App Engine's case the sessions are stored in the Datastore, with probably some caching. So it's still a call to the datastore.

That should be totally acceptable, however if it turns out managing a session really decreases you app's performance, you can always store the data in an encrypted cookie. That way the information is provided by the browser every time it sends an HTTP request. Note that it means you must get encryption right and that HTTP requests will be slightly bigger (the size of the encrypted data).

So in the end it's a tradeoff. I would recommend sticking to sessions unless you experience performance issues. The advantage of sessions (compared to your fist approach) is that if you ever want to store additional data, you will have less code to add.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood , in App Engine, there is no commitment regarding the durability of data stored in Memcache. The OP could store a session and it could be gone in the next 15 minutes or in the next hour, or never. I would not recommend App Engine's Memcache to store sessions, only to cache them.